# YouTube crashing Shockwave Flash in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I have been having a problem with viewing YouTube in Chrome recently which is absolutely driving me up the wall.

Videos have been intermittently breaking up (by which I mean the audio breaks up and the FPS drops). These break ups last for about 2 seconds and then everything plays fine. For about a minute. Then the same thing happens.

Using Windows Task Manager and Chrome Task Manager I found that the plugin Shockwave Flash was eating all of my CPU. So much so that the CPU usage on Task Manager would be consistently at 100% and stay like that for a good few minutes.

Using Google I found that Chrome has an in built flash player which could be messing things up. So I downloaded the standalone version of flash and disabled PepperFlash. This has had little effect. I also disabled hardware acceleration which managed to reduce the amount of time my CPU was at 100%. The break ups still happen, but they are less frequent. I have two extensions: AdBlock and Youtube Center. I know that neither of them are eating CPU because Chrome's task manager showed that the only CPU intensive plugin was Shockwave Flash. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you right click on the video and select "Stats for nerds", do you see `accelerated video rendering, accelerated video decoding`?

Comment: @yjwong no... :(

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Chrome? It syncs extensions, settings, history- essentially all of your data, so it shouldn't be a big deal to uninstall.

Comment: Just to try and remove other factors that may be causing your issue I'd remove all extentions or go into in-cognito mode and watch youtube on there to see if your still seeing the 100% on the CPU. Also from my experience pepper flash has been running smoother for me compared to the adobe version.

Comment: @imulsion What do you see? Is it `software` for both? Do you have issues playing videos (i.e. MP4/H.264 videos) using say, Media Player Classic or Windows Media Player?

Comment: @yjwong It was just youtube breaking up as I described with 100% CPU jumps. I found out it was a performance issue from the linked question. I found out that the CPU was consistently at 80 degrees Celsius which was affecting my performance. A clean out of the fan fixed the problem.

Comment: Ah I see, thought it might be because the CPU wasn't beefy enough to decode the video and hence should rely on the GPU instead (which is better for the job, anyway). Glad you got it fixed!